# Including json schema files in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am writing an Angular 2 app with Typescript using the angular-cli tool.
I have a bunch of JSON schemas for my back-end API that I want to reference in my typescript so I can pass those schemas to a schema validator.  What is the best way to include the .json files so I can reference them as a variable in my typescript and also have them bundled properly when I do a build with angular-cli?

My first thought was to make a custom module and export each schema as a const.  I am not sure if that's possible and have been unable to find any example syntax on how to reference the files.

Here is my example code that works now.  The only problem is I had to copy the schema file contents into my typesrcipt.  I want to be able to reference the original schema file.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { WlanStatus } from "./wlan-status";
import { JsonValidatorService } from "../../json-validator.service";

//import WlanStatusSchema from "../../../api/app/plugins/wifi/schemas/getStatus.json";
const wlanStatusSchema =
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "result": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "cardState": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "profileName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "clientMAC": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "clientIP": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "ipv4"
                },
                "clientName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "AP_MAC": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "AP_IP": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "APName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Channel": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "RSSI": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "bitRate": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "txPower": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "DTIM": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "beaconPeriod": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "SSID": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "currentRadioMode": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "cardState",
                "profileName",
                "clientMAC",
                "clientIP",
                "clientName",
                "AP_MAC",
                "AP_IP",
                "APName",
                "Channel",
                "RSSI",
                "bitRate",
                "txPower",
                "DTIM",
                "beaconPeriod",
                "SSID",
                "currentRadioMode"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "result"
    ]
};

@Injectable()
export class WlanService
{
    private getStatusUrl = 'app/getWlanStatus';  // URL to web API

    constructor(private http: Http, private validator: JsonValidatorService) { }

scan(): void
{
    console.log("Scanning for APs...")
}

getStatus(): Observable<WlanStatus>
{
    return this.issueRequest(this.getStatusUrl, wlanStatusSchema);
}

private issueRequest(requestUrl: string, schema: any): Observable<Object>
{
    return this.http.get(requestUrl)
        .map((res: Response) =>
        {
            let body = res.json();
            let valid = this.validator.validate(schema, body.data);
            if (!valid)
            {
                throw (new TypeError("Not a valid response: " + JSON.stringify(this.validator.getErrors())));
            }

            return body.data.result;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response | any)
{
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response)
    {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else
    {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am using angular-cli and it uses webpack, I was able to solve my issue by using the require() function.  Webpack will properly bundle the .json file this way.

I created a typescript file to import all my schemas, wlan-schema.ts:

```
export const WlanStatusSchema = require("../../../../api/app/plugins/wifi/schemas/getStatus.json");
```

to use it in my wlan.service.ts:

```
import * as schema from "./wlan-schema";

this.validator.validate(schema.WlanStatusSchema, apiResp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the back-end API, you can add new API Point to fetch JSON file. Then in your Angular application, you should be able to consume that API Point using [HTTP Client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html). From that, you can get the JSON file content and assign it to a variable in typescript.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that would work, but not for my scenario.  The issue is that I want to be able to reference the .json file contents directly in my front end code.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be setting up class files to use to validate the schema? Then your visual studio will show up such errors as you create the.

Something like
    export class Hero {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. This is an example of an register form.

I used [@types/json-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/json-schema) for the type (JSONSchema4).

**register.component.ts**

```
...
import * as registerSchema from '../../../../shared/schemas/api/create-user.json';
import {JSONSchema4} from 'json-schema';
... 
export class RegisterComponent {
    registerSchema: JSONSchema4 = registerSchema;
    constructor(){
         console.log(registerSchema.$schema);
    }
}
```

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.json' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```